# Why does WeightedAdjacencyMatrix take the weight for absent edges to be zero?

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

According to Wolfram documentation, WeightedAdjacencyGraph[*wmat*] gives the graph with weighted adjacency matrix *wmat*, while WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[*g*] 
supposedly does the reverse, giving the adjacency matrix of edge weights of the graph *g*. Yet **WeightedAdjacencyGraph takes Infinity to be the absence of an edge, while WeightedAdjacencyMatrix takes the weight of an absent edge to be zero**.

This wouldn’t be so bad if completing the round trip were simply a matter of replacing zero with Infinity, but zero is a legitimate weight in a WeightedAdjacencyGraph, meaning an edge of weight zero, not an absent edge. Therefore, there is no way to decide from a WeightedAdjacencyMatrix which zeros mean zero-weighted edges and which zeros mean no edges.

I’m looking both for an explanation of this unexpected behavior and for suggestions on how to work around it. It’s easy enough to write my own version of WeightedAdjacencyMatrix that takes the weight of an absent edge to be Infinity, but I doubt I could match the performance of the built-in function.  Besides, I half expected to find an Option in the existing version for this choice, so I’m holding out some hope that I just couldn’t find it.

Comment: Well, no one here know *why* it was done like this.  Only Wolfram does.  I *strongly* suggest that you write to Wolfram Support and ask about this.  I find this implementation very annoying and have complained about it to Wolfram on more than one occasion. It was stated more than once here that issues which are reported by more people are taken more seriously, so please report it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Will do. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: It is probably an oversight from having written the WeightedAdjacencyMatrix function for a shortest path algorithm that works with matrices instead of a more efficient graph representation. In that representation it is convenient to represent missing edges by infinity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a workaround: this is a graph with some zero-weight edges:

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 1, 4 <-> 5, 1 <-> 5, 
    2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 5},
   EdgeWeight -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[FindShortestPath[g, 1, 3]]]
```

[image]

`WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` shows zeros for the missing edges *and* the actual zero weight edges, however the un-weighted adjacency matrix has only zeros for absent edges, so we can use that:

```
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g] // MatrixForm
AdjacencyMatrix[g] // MatrixForm
MatrixForm[
 Normal[( Normal@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g]  /. 0 -> "zw") AdjacencyMatrix[g] +
     "zw" IdentityMatrix[Length@VertexList[g]]]
       /. {0 -> Infinity, "zw" -> 0}]
```

> [image]

If you want `Infinity` on the diagonal, which is what `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` want:

```
MatrixForm[
 wam = Normal[( 
      Normal@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g] /. 0 -> "zw") AdjacencyMatrix[g]] /. 
        {0 -> Infinity, "zw" -> 0}]
```

[image]

then `WeightedAdjacencyGraph[wam]` returns the original.

in case you want to put that back to `SparseArray` form:

```
  SparseArray[wam, ConstantArray[Length@VertexList[g], 2], Infinity]
```

Another approach may be to note the `SparseArray` has explicit zeros for the actual zero weight positions, so in principle you can switch the `SparseArray` default value.  I cant see how to do that except by manually editing the `FullForm`

Comment: That’s clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[`WeightedAdjacencyGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyGraph.html) takes `Infinity` (not `0`!) to represent absent connections.

The [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) package provides the `IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` and `IGWeightedAdjacencyMatrix` functions, both of which let you specify which element should represent absent connections. By default, zero is used in both.

---

Here's a function that is analogous to [`WeightedAdjacencyMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyMatrix.html), but also allows specifying the element that represents absent connections.

```
Options[weightedAdjacencyMatrix] = Options[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix];
weightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph_?GraphQ, unconnected : Except[_?OptionQ] : 0, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=     
With[{sa = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph, opt]},
  SparseArray[sa["NonzeroPositions"] -> sa["NonzeroValues"], Dimensions[sa], unconnected]
]
```

(But [Carl's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165159/12) is probably faster.)

---

Since `IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` is implemented purely in Mathematica, I will copy here its current implementation (Feb 2018).  It relies on an undocumented syntax of `Graph` where edges are given in terms of vertex *indices* (not vertex names).

Example:  `Graph[{a,b,c}, {{1,2}, {1,3}}]` gives the same graph as `Graph[{a,b,c}, {a<->b, a<->c}]`.  Since the index-based edge list may be a packed array, operations on it can be very fast. This implementation of `IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` is typically slightly faster than `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`—I believe for this reason.

```
IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[wam_?SquareMatrixQ, unconnected : Except[_?OptionQ] : 0, opt : OptionsPattern[Graph]] :=
    IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[Range@Length[wam], wam, unconnected, opt]

IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[vertices_List, wam_?SquareMatrixQ, unconnected : Except[_?OptionQ] : 0, opt : OptionsPattern[Graph]] :=
    Module[{sa = SparseArray[wam, Automatic, unconnected], directedEdges = OptionValue[DirectedEdges]},
      If[Length[vertices] != Length[sa],
        Message[IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph::ndims, vertices, wam];
        Return[$Failed]
      ];
      If[directedEdges === Automatic,
        directedEdges = Not@SymmetricMatrixQ[sa]
      ];
      If[Not[directedEdges],
        sa = UpperTriangularize[sa]
      ];
      Graph[vertices, sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], DirectedEdges -> directedEdges, opt]
    ]
```

The key parts of the code are:

- Re-build the sparse matrix with the desired background element: `sa = SparseArray[wam, Automatic, unconnected]`. Note that this does not change the matrix (like in Carl's answer). It simply changes what is stored explicitly.
- Extract the non-zero positions and values to build the weighted graph: `Graph[vertices, sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"]`

The rest is just for handling directed/undirected graphs and error checking.

Answer (score 5):

Concerning your statement:

> Therefore, there is no way to decide from a WeightedAdjacencyMatrix which zeros mean zero-weighted edges and which zeros mean no edges.

This is not true. The [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) representation that is used for the [`WeightedAdjacencyMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyMatrix) uses explicit zeros  and background zeros. The explicit zeros represent the zero-weighted edges, and the background zeros mean that there is no edge. Now, the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) of a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) object is something like:

$$\operatorname{SparseArray}[\operatorname{Automatic},\operatorname{\
dimensions},\operatorname{background},\{\operatorname{index},\operatorname{\
location},\operatorname{values}\}]$$

Here the background is 0, representing the background zeros, and the values field lists the explicit values, and can include an explicit zero as well.

So, as @george2079 alluded to, the way to convert non-edge zeros into [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity) is to just replace the background 0 with [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity), while leaving the explicit zeros in the values field alone.

Here is a way to do so:

```
setBackground[Verbatim[SparseArray][a_,b_,_,c__], new_] := SparseArray[a, b, new, c]
```

Using @george2079's example:

```
wam = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g];
wam //MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Using `setBackground`:

```
setBackground[wam, Infinity] //MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  \infty  & 1 & \infty  & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & \infty  & 1 & \infty  & 0 \\
>  \infty  & 1 & \infty  & 1 & 2 \\
>  1 & \infty  & 1 & \infty  & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & \infty  \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't understand. The point was that explicitly stored elements shouldn't change, only the background, and that's what my function does. I especially don't want to rebuild the sparse array because then explicitly stored elements that are the same as the background get dropped.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.