# How to modify the default value of a `SparseArray` without intermediate non sparse matrices

Tags: sparse-arrays

How to modify the default value of a `SparseArray`? All of my ideas doesn't work, because of the `ReadProtected` attribute. Is there a string such that

```
mat = SparseArray[{}, {100, 100}]
mat["something"] = 1;
```

is a solution?

Comment: `mat = SparseArray[{}, {100, 100}, 1]`

Comment: @corey979 I don't know the first argument for that, unless I use `SparseArray[Normal[mat], Automatic, 1]`, which has a non sparse intermediate

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The third argument of `SparseArray` sets a background; then e.g. `mat[[56, 75]]` gives `1`. You can also check the background with `mat["Background"]`.

Comment: [This thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131834/directly-change-the-background-value-of-a-sparsearray) might also be useful.